# Do I need to geocode countries/popular locations to add as markers to Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocode

I have a script that generates a ton of locations/places based on a users input. I want to add these places as markers on Google Maps based on javascript APIv3, but I would easily go over the geocoding limit.

Is there a way simply to insert a string of a popular location into the markers options variable and have it load on the map? So insert "Boston, USA" instead of latlng(X,Y)? Are their other options available to me? I know of free geocoding APIs, but not all my locations are in the US.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to specify a Marker's location in Google Maps JavaScript API v3 is with a LatLng object.  You cannot specify the Marker's location with a common name like "Boston, USA".

One thing you may want to consider is how a map will perform with lots of Markers.  (I'm assuming by "a ton" you mean at least 500.)  That might heavily tax your user's computer/device and the user may end up with little more than a blob of markers that's less than completely useful.  Perhaps you can test with, say, 1000 markers on a less-than-kickass machine and see how your code performs.  You may find that you need to rethink your interface in a way that reduces the number of markers you use anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I was thinking about that as well, and saw that a clever solution to group markers together existed: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2009/04/markerclusterer-solution-to-too-many.html

Or I could provide a density map. Either way, the rate limiting factor here is my lack of ability to geocode.

Comment: Not sure what your budget is like for this project, but you can get a Google Maps Premier license and then you can geocode 100,000 addresses a day rather than 2500.  Google Maps Premier starts at $10,000.